# Using Django Server Sent Events with Database post save

Tags: django, generator, server-sent-events

I am trying to implement Server Sent Events(SSE) in Django Framework. It is clear to me that I can implement a `view` like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def event_stream(request):
    def eventStream():
        yield "data:Server Sent Data\n\n"

    response = HttpResponse(eventStream(), content_type="text/event-stream")
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    return response
```

But I want to trigger the SSE call whenever a new entry is made in a database table, from the `post_save` of the table, How I might be able to achieve that here since `eventStream` here is a generator function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django is build around the request/response cycle which means that it doesn't work well with websockets or even SSE. In your example there is no way to propagade the post_save signal to the view unless you use subscribe to a queue (rabbitmq, redis pubsub) in the view and send data in the signal handler.

Consider other solutions to push from the server:

- Long polling
- [Django channels](https://github.com/django/channels)
- An asynchronus solution like nodejs or tornado instead or alongside Django

Comment: Among all, Django channels is neatest.

Answer (score -1):

Read about signals.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/
In this case, you should use request_started and post_save signals