# How to redirect data automatically from server to Client

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, react-redux

I am working on a web application using python3.5 for the backend, javascript +react/redux for the frontend and a Django server.

The goal of the application is to display in real time data sent by some raspberry PI running under different protocols (MQTT, XMPP and CoaP). I tell my django server to make get request to differents servers which handles different protocols, then save those data into a database that i can finally retrieve into my redux store and then display those on my client.

I would like to be able to remove the saving in database part which means that my Django server has to forward data it receives directly to the client side.

I've made some researches and it seems that websocket programming is the best way to do it but i have such a different architecture so i'm not sure that i will be able to use this except if i restart from scratch which would be awful. If you have any other ideas to do what i want or if you have some advice to transform my app it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar problems, and there are several ways to solve it. The best, in my opinion is using [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) like this:

in javascript client:

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("myScriptInRpi");

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  //code
}
```

The advantage is that you could send data directly from raspberry PI to client. But If you want it from [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556439/using-django-server-sent-events-with-database-post-save) you could do it.